# async/await not working in console application

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I'm totally green with TPL and want to execute an async method in a console application.

My code:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Task<string> t = MainAsync();
        t.Wait();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task<string> MainAsync()
    {
        var result = await (new Task<string>(() => { return "Test"; }));
        return result;

    }
```

This task runs forever. Why? What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't start your task. This is why `Wait` doesn't return. Try

```
var result = await Task.Run<string>(() => { return "Test"; });
```